# pyspark dataframe operate on multiple columns dynamically

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

In **pyspark**, suppose I have dataframe with columns named as `'a1','a2','a3'...'a99'`, how do I apply operation on each of them to create new columns with new names dynamically?

For example, to getnew columns such as  `sum('a1') as 'total_a1' , ... sum('a99') as 'total_a99'`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a list comprehension with `alias`.

To return only the new columns:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as f
df1 = df.select(*[f.sum(c).alias("total_"+c) for c in df.columns])
```

And if you wanted to keep the existing columns as well:

```
df2 = df.select("*", *[f.sum(c).alias("total_"+c) for c in df.columns])
```